# Two URLs with same AJAX structure

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Is there any option to use two urls ((post & get) or (post & post)) in same **AJAX** structure ??? or some cooler format???

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "save.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function(chat_list) { }
 });
```

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "view.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function(chat_list) { }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just use javascript variables.

```
var ajaxMethod = "POST";
var ajaxUrl = "save.php";

$.ajax({
    type: ajaxMethod,
    url: ajaxUrl,
    data: dataString,
    success: function(chat_list) { 
    }
});
```